# r function not return any result

Tags: r, function

I have created the following function. R should return 1 as a result but I doesn't give any result?

```
phrasedis <- function(string, phrase1, phrase2,n) { 
  char1 <- unlist(gregexpr(phrase1,string))
  char2 <- unlist(gregexpr(phrase2,string))

    for  ( i in 1: 2) {
      for (j in 1: 2) {
         pos1[i] <- sapply(strsplit(substr(text, 0,char1[i]-1),"\\s"),length)+1
         pos2[j] <- sapply(strsplit(substr(text, 0,char2[j]-1),"\\s"),length)+1
         dist <- pos2[i] - pos1[j]

         a <- ifelse(pos1[i]>0 & pos2[j]>0 & dist>0 & dist<=6,1,0)
         if (a==1) break
         return(a)
      }

    }
}

text <- "phone rang a b c d e f z y z phone rang but no answer"
b <- sapply(text, FUN=function(str) phrasedis(str,"phone rang" , "no answer",6))
```

What it should do is return 1 if the distance between phone rang and no answer is less than 6 words, otherwise return 0. 
Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Hi Joris, thank you but after removing break, it still doesn't give me any result.

Comment: That's because your function has no objects `pos1` and `pos2` defined before you want to change them. Add `pos1 <- pos2 <- c(0,0)` before your loop and move the return statement to the absolute end of your function.

Comment: Hi, sorry it does return  1 but when I change text into "phone rang a b c d e f z y z phone rang d e f" it still returns 1. Looks like it returns 1 no matter what text is.

Comment: I did mentioned at the end of the post that it should return 1 if the number of words between "phone rang" and "no answer" is less than 6 words, otherwise it should return 0. The problem is "phone rang" and "no answer" may occur 2 times or more in the text. I want R to stop as soon as a=1 and the function return 1 as the result. If a is still 0, the loop continues until it reaches the last occurrences of "phone rang" and "no answer". If at that point, a is still 0 then the function return 0. My problem is I don't know how to make my function do it.

Comment: A correct logic could be `function(...) { ... for () { for () { ... if (a==1) break } } return(a) }`

Comment: @baver your code is not doing that. See my answer.

Answer (score 4):

The logic of your function is wrong.

First of all, you put the `return()` statement inside the loop, so the loop stops always in the first iteration due to that `return()` statement.

Then, you don't create the vectors `pos1` and `pos2`, so your function can't even work. The only reason you don't complain about an error, is because you have a `pos1` and `pos2` in your global environment probably.

But even when placing the return statement where it's supposed to go (at the end!) and creating a pos1 and pos2 vector of length 2, your function can't work because your loop is wrong.

You loop over 1 and 2, which doesn't make sense at all unless you have exact 2 matches for both `phrase1` and `phrase2` in `string`. Due to that and the fact there is only 1 match for `phrase2`, when `j==2` the outcome of the `substr(text, 0, char2[j] -1)` is NA, which has an exact length of 1 so pos2[j] becomes 2. Meanwhile pos1[i] is still `1`, which fulfills your condition and hence `1` is returned.

This is how you could do it:

```
phrasedis <- function(string, phrase1, phrase2,n) { 
  char1 <- gregexpr(phrase1,string)[[1]]
  char2 <- gregexpr(phrase2,string)[[1]]

  # -1 is returned if no match was found for either phrase
  if(any(c(char1,char2) == -1)){
    return(0)
  }
  # Calculate the end positions of the words
  end1 <- char1 + attr(char1, "match.length")

  #set a to 0
  a <- 0
  # loop over all matches in char1
  for(i in seq_along(char1)){
    # Find the closest match for phrase 2
    thepos <- which.min(abs(char2 - end1[i]))
    # get all words in between.
    # Don't forget to trim white spaces before and after
    inbetween <- trimws(substring(string, end1[i], char2[thepos]-1))
    inbetween <- strsplit(inbetween,"\\s")[[1]]
    if(length(inbetween) <= n){
      a <- 1
      break
    }

  }
  return(a)
}
```

This is how it works:

```
> text <- "phone rang a b cd phone rang d e f g h i no answer"

> phrasedis(text,"phone rang" , "no answer",6)
[1] 1

> text <- " There is nothing in this text"

> phrasedis(text,"phone rang" , "no answer",6)
[1] 0

> text <- "No answer but the phone rang"

> phrasedis(text,"phone rang" , "no answer",6)
[1] 0
```

Comment: Thank a lot for your detailed answer. I am new to R and this is my first function, your answer really helped.